# Run cmd command with C# code

Tags: c#, cmd

i wil try to run this command:

> "G:\Arml\Automation\Aystem\Programs\BCompare.exe
>   @G:\Arml\Automation\System\bcomp_script.txt c:\text1.txt
>   c:\text2.txt c:\a.xml";

In c# but nothing it's not execute the result

What the correct code i need?

Comment: What is the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

In C# you should starc another Process to run `cmd.exe`. If you check it in console and your command string doesn't have any mistakes you can do it like this:

```
string commandText;
commandText= @"/c G:\Arml\Automation\Aystem\Programs\BCompare.exe G:\Arml\Automation\System\bcomp_script.txt c:\text1.txt c:\text2.txt c:\a.xml";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",commandText);
```

Comment: it's dosent work is just open the cmd windopws and not run the command line :(

Comment: This command text is ought to be something like `@"/c G:\Arml\Automation\Aystem\Programs\BCompare.exe G:\Arml\Automation\System\bcomp_script.txt c:\text1.txt c:\text2.txt c:\a.xml"`

Comment: @Jelly could be. I just can't test it. only OP can

Comment: We just have to wait until OP bestows some more clearance upon us.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can run the program "BCompare.exe" without running "cmd.exe"

```
string exename = @"G:\Arml\Automation\Aystem\Programs\BCompare.exe";
string args = @"@G:\Arml\Automation\System\bcomp_script.txt c:\text1.txt c:\text2.txt c:\a.xml";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(exename, args);
```

Comment: i get error : An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Comment: I've corected the answer format. In "teo van kot" answer you should remove second @

Comment: If you really need it, I've corrected code again. Please, try

Comment: agian this error An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll